# Installing Dropbox API for C#

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, dropbox-api

I am following the instructions here for installing the Dropbox API for C#.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#install

Those instructions are to run `Install-Package Dropbox.Api` in powershell.

I get the following error:

```
PS > Install-Package Dropbox.Api
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Dropbox.Api'. Try
Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Dropbox.Api
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Doing a bit of googling there are suggestions for the general case of this error message to specify a `PackageSource`.  But I can not find the correct package source for dropbox.

My sources of packages like this:

```
PS > Get-PackageSource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

How can I get the Dropbox API installed for C# for Visual Studio 2017?

[EDIT] I tried:

```
PS > Install-Package Get-PackageSource -Version 4.3.0
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Version'.
At line:1 char:35
+ Install-Package Get-PackageSource -Version 4.3.0
+                                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

[EDIT]  I tried `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage packages` and could find the package there.

[EDIT] I tried installing Dropbox.Api using `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage Packages` and get: `Package restore failed.  Rolling back package changes`.  There was a message that flashed before the error, but it was just the location of the project in my directory structure.

[EDIT]  Following @smarx suggestion of running from package manager console rather than powershell:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Michael Potter\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj...
Install-Package : Package Dropbox.Api 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Dropbox.Api 4.3.0 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-dnxcore50+net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Dropbox.Api
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Dropbox.Api
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.9676774
PM>
```

So that is very good progress as now we get some kind of error message.

Comment: In Visual Studio, try Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage packages, and look for it there

Comment: Try `Install-Package Dropbox.Api -Version 4.3.0`.  Actually, using dropbox api directly using `HttpClient` is very easy.  One less DLL to reference to.

Comment: @AllenKing Thanks for the tip and just using httpclient directly.  I am going to look into that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1' while installing new package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908613/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-consoleapp1-while-ins)

Answer (score 1):

> Those instructions are to run `Install-Package Dropbox.Api` in powershell.

The instructions actually say to run that command in the [**Package Manager Console**](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console). Open the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio, and make sure that your prompt looks like `PM >`, not `PS >`.

Answer (score 0):

I posted two questions thinking they were different, but they turned out to have the same solution:

[Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1' while installing new package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908613/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-consoleapp1-while-ins)

I am closing this question as a duplicate.