# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1' while installing new package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I get `Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1'` while installing a new package.  In particular I am trying to install the dropbox API, but I tried several other packages and get the same result.

I install by right clicking on the project and choosing `Manage nuGet Packages...`  Then I select the package and click Install.

The NuGet is able to connect with the NuGet server as the package seems to download.  The download information flashes on the screen pretty quick so I captured it with screen recording software to see if there were error messages.  There were none.

I updated visual studio 2017 to latest patch level.  My windows 10 machine is also at the latest level.

The project I am trying to install into is a freshly created `Console App(.Net Core)`.

Here are the other questions I looked at:

[Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906856/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes)
does not have any responses because it is not a well developed question.

[package restore failed rolling back package change for ' myproject' in vs 2017 .net mvc core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856314/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-change-for-myproject-in-vs-2017)
Yet another poorly worded question with no viable answers.

[Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'myproject' in vs 2017 in MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784052/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-myproject-in-vs-2017)
That one is trying to update packages, not install new.

[Nuget - Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'. 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059543/nuget-package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-webapplication)
Seems to be for a custom package.

I am new to using Visual Studio.

Comment: It would be helpful if you vote this down to also add a comment as to why.  As far as I can tell this is a perfect question for stack...  I have an error message that I don't know how to fix and I listed the things I did to try to fix it.  I acknowledge it is really a noob question, but stack serves people of all levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Michael Potter's answer, create a Console App (.NET Framework), NOT Console App (.NET Core).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I am using `Console App(.Net Core)`  Core is not compatible with Dropbox API.

I figured that out by opening `NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` and running `Install-Package Dropbox-Api`.

Then the error message about compatibility was on the screen plain to see.

To solve the problem I am switching to `Console App (.Net Framework)`.

Answer (score 0):

bring the version of the solution package to 1.1.3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZck7.jpg)